# Gradle exported properties dont work with gradle bootRun in Spring

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

in my Spring Boot project i have the following fragment in **gradle** which exports gradle properties to Spring Environment.

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/application.properties") {
        expand(project.properties)
    } 
}
```

My **application.properties** looks like this (snippet)

> app.version=${jar.version}

Works pretty well. I can work with the gradle propeties in Spring classes with **@value** and even can access them in thymeleaf with

**th:text="${@environment.getProperty('app.version')}**

But now the issue: When i run the same project with "gradle bootRun". I am getting this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jar.version' in string value "${jar.version}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

I assume its something about the way gradle's bootRun works by not using processResources or something like that?

The question would be: how can i get this to work. I dont want to give up using bootRun.

Comment: just saw that its explained here github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1739 , but cant see any solution to my problem. I dont mind if these values dont show up in bootRun but my application should run at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a default value to use when the real one cannot be found?

```
@Value("${...:defaultValue}")
```

Comment: this is ok for $Value in java classes but doesnt solve my problem with th:text="${@environment.getProperty('app.version')} but i can workaround this issue. Thanks.